# NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate calculates incorrectly by 60 minutes

Tags: swift, datetime

Trying to figure out why the following code results in **90,000** which is exactly 1 hour over a day.  The created dates are both set to noon of consecutive days so the answer should be **86,400** (24*60*60).

```
let currentCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar();
let components1 = NSDateComponents()
components1.year = 2015
components1.month = 11
components1.day = 1
components1.hour = 12
components1.minute = 0
components1.second = 0
let myDate1 = currentCalendar.dateFromComponents(components1)!

let components2 = NSDateComponents()
components2.year = 2015
components2.month = 10
components2.day = 31
components2.hour = 12
components2.minute = 0
components2.second = 0
let myDate2 = currentCalendar.dateFromComponents(components2)!

let difference = myDate1.timeIntervalSinceDate(myDate2)
```

Running swift 2 (Xcode 7.0)

Comment: Is it just those two dates? What if you use midnight of one day and 23:59:59 of the same day?

Comment: Your code result here is  86400. Are you experiencing changes in your daylight savings time?

Comment: print your dates and check the time

Comment: Are you in Canada or some other country where daylight savings time changes on October 31st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daylight savings time ends on Nov 1, 2015. The 25-hour difference is correct. There will also be a 23-hour day in the spring when DST begins.

This is why, if you want to be sure to get the same clock time on another date, you can’t just add or subtract multiples of 24 hours.

This only goes for places that observe DST, which is probably why some commenters on the original question are seeing a 24-hour difference in their local time zone.